# Android Studio: Best Method to Save and Retrieve User Input Data

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-database

I am new to Android development and need some help. I want to create an app that will log user input information for different tests.

In the first activity, the user will create a hole by inputting different unique information such as ID, location, date, etc. In the second activity, in that hole, the user can conduct a test with unique information such as depth, time, test type, etc. In the same hole, multiple tests can be conducted (for ex. Hole #1 will have test #1, test #2, test #3...). After the user conducts all the necessary tests in the hole, the user can create another hole (hole #2) and repeat (the user can create as many holes and tests as they need). In the third activity, the user can review the information of all of the holes they created and the respective tests in each hole.

Currently, I have the first and second activities set as a simple form using edit texts. In the third activity, I am planning on using dependant spinners to select the hole and respective test and a popup window to display the test information.

I am passing the data between activities using intents but this method will only work for the first hole and first test. How can I save and retrieve all of the data?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something quick and simple look into `Singleton`s it will allow you to store data in a static context so you can retrieve it app wide. Its not the best solution but it  will work.

The problem really stems from the lack of an overarching control structure the way you have this set up is forcing you to play hot potato with your data between `Activities`. The `Activities` should probably be reporting to a single source of information, and retrieving information from that source. This could be a `ViewModel`, `Singleton`, or another `Activity` that is supposed to manage the test.